# golang can't start debug, shows framework not found CoreFoundation

Tags: go

I'm using Macbook pro m1, after data migration or update to monterey（not sure which cause this）, golang seems can't debug or go list -compiled. I tried to reinstall/update golang and the result is same

go version: 1.17.3 darwin/arm64

Error msg when I start debug

```sh
Build Error: go build -o /var/folders/x8/s3w_s9rj0qj74hs68wvqs1740000gp/T/__debug_bin4251008076 -gcflags all=-N -l .
# runtime/cgo
ld: framework not found CoreFoundation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (exit status 2)
```

Error msg when go list -compiled

```sh
# runtime/cgo
ld: framework not found CoreFoundation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
confcenter
```

what can i do, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You need to reinstall the CommandLineTools. `xcode-select` says everything is up to date, but this information seems to be false.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Re-installing didn't help for me. I still get that error. Apple M1 Max, MacOS: 13.3 (22E252)