# How to solve the error ld: framework not found CoreFoundation while installing GOPLS?

Tags: visual-studio, go, visual-studio-code, delve, gopls

I am using Apple M1 Pro 12.0.1 (21A559).
with go version : go1.19.3 darwin/arm64

When I am trying to install gopls, I get the following error.

```
go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
```

golang.org/x/tools/gopls
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: framework not found CoreFoundation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 2,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.3.0\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.10.1\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.2.1-0.20221101170700-b5bc717366b2\ngo: downloading github.com/sergi/go-diff v1.1.0\ngo: downloading honnef.co/go/tools v0.3.3\ngo: downloading mvdan.cc/gofumpt v0.3.1\ngo: downloading mvdan.cc/xurls/v2 v2.4.0\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.1.0\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.6.0\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20220722155255-886fb9371eb4\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/vuln v0.0.0-20221010193109-563322be2ea9\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.4.0\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/exp/typeparams v0.0.0-20220722155223-a9213eeb770e\ngo: downloading golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20220722155223-a9213eeb770e\ngo: downloading github.com/BurntSushi/toml v1.2.0\ngo: downloading github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.8\n# golang.org/x/tools/gopls\n/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1\nld: framework not found CoreFoundation\nclang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)\n\n"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70031053/golang-cant-start-debug-shows-framework-not-found-corefoundation

Answer (score 2):

What is the Target in `clang --version`?

I had the same issue and found that the clang binary (I was mistakenly using from a python conda env) had a Target of x86_64-apple-darwin22.2.0.  I deleted that binary from my python env and then the clang binary from  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin was picked up.

So before I had:

```
~/ ❯ clang --version                                                                                                                                                      Py base
clang version 13.0.1
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/robtaylor/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin
```

Then after I deleted the unwanted binary using `rm /Users/robtaylor/opt/anaconda3/envs/py38/bin/clang*` I had:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

So the Target was arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0, which is now correct.